# Hotmail Contact List

Tags: php, windows-live

Can someone tell me step by step how to get contacts (emails) from Windows Live API in php.. using oauth

i have implemented gmail,yahoo,aol easily, but i am unable to implement this.
The furthest i have able to go is authenicate a user from live .. redirect to my site but the uri it hits using curl returns nothing

https://livecontacts.services.live.com/users/@C@-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/rest/livecontacts

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to login you should get a Cookie, in the Cookie you will get a token autentification, them you will get the information building a http request with:

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/contacts?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 0):

Hotmail will not give the information (emails).

The option, make a curl call to login, and log into it.

Them make a second curl call to the contact page and parse all the information.

Oskar